# Is it possible to generate push notification or send "event data" from AWS lambda to Mobile Analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-mobile-analytics

Sample code not working

```
mobileanalytics.putEvents(params, function(err, data) { 
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred 
else     console.log(data);           // successful response 
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more details here? Namely, how are you instantiating your mobileanalytics client (please censor your appId/cognitoPoolId) and what error are you seeing?

Comment: Had properly initialized the mobileanalytics object (with proper cognitoPoolId and an  IAM role),but i have doubt Is it possible to put events from lambda function to mobileanalytics?

Comment: even i had tried mobileAnalyticsClient.submitEvents();

Comment: It is possible to submit from Lambda to Amazon Mobile Analytics.

Comment: Could u explain me how?